# Convert uchar Mat to float Mat in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV, if I have a Mat img that contains uchar data, how do I convert the data into float? Is there a function available? Thank you.

Comment: In Python, since the images are NumPy arrays, you can use `img = img.astype(np.float32)`.

Answer (score 67):

If you meant c++ then you have

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
Mat img;
img.create(2,2,CV_8UC1);
Mat img2;
img.convertTo(img2, CV_32FC1); // or CV_32F works (too)
```

details in opencv2refman.pdf.

**UPDATE:**

CV_32FC1 is for 1-channel (C1, i.e. grey image) float valued (32F) pixels

CV_8UC1 is for 1-channel (C1, i.e. grey image) unsigned char (8UC) valued ones.

**UPDATE 2:**
According to Arthur Tacca, only `CV_32F` is correct (or presumably CV_8U), since convertTo should not change the number of channels. It sounds logical right? Nevertheless, when I have checked opencv reference manual, I could not find any info about this, but I agree with him.

Comment: Can you please tell me where we need to use `32F` and `8U`

Comment: this is actually my question , why where we need to use float valued pixel and where we need to use char valued ones

Comment: It depends on the bitdepth. If your grayscale image has the depth of 256 different colors, then it is 8UC1. The typical cases are 32FC1 for grayscale and 8UC3 for color.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Does this work with multi-channel images as well (i.e. convert CV_8UC3 to CV_8FC3)?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can try it with small images using matrix constructors to confirm that it works. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Comment: You should use `CV_32F`, NOT `CV_32FC1`, because `convertTo` takes a bit depth, not a number of channels. It is probably just coincidence that `CV_32FC1` works, because it has the same numerical value as `CV_32F`. I wouldn't expect e.g. `CV_32FC3` to work because it has a different numerical value. Note that `convertTo` never changes the number of channels in the image.

Comment: @AHF to answer more to your question as where to we need to use `32F` and `8U` its difficult to understand without an example . The Kinect (v2) sensor for example has an IR sensor that measures depth and returns the depth of each corresponding pixel in mm (between 500mm  and 4500mm). So if you would want to view the depth image in grayscale from the kinect  one pixel of the `cv::Mat` would have to store a float, say`2325.32`  for example. In such cases using `8UC1` would not yield intended results and should rather be used to store unsigned char 8-bit representations of values between 0-255.

Answer (score 10):

Use `cvConvert` function. In Python:

```
import cv
m = cv.CreateMat(2, 2, cv.CV_8UC1)
m1 = cv.CreateMat(2, 2, cv.CV_32FC1)
cv.Convert(m, m1)
```