# How to scale the pixel values in the range [0,1] in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

You can scale the pixel values ​​of a matrix of type uchar Mat in the range [0,1] and storing them in a Mat of type float?

When I try to divide all pixels by 255 and store them in Mat of type float, I do not find in it the values ​​between [0,1] but the integer values zero and one.

Comment: You forgot to show us your code.

Comment: `uchar` means `unsigned char` which is an integer type so a `uchar` can never have a value `0<x<1`.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Convert uchar Mat to float Mat in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302171/convert-uchar-mat-to-float-mat-in-opencv)

After this, you can simply divide by 255 to get the range from 0 to 1

Comment: Might need to divide by 255.0 just to make sure floating point division (not integer division) is used. Better yet, scale by 1.0/255.0.