# Curvedness output

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to calculate the curvedness of an image. The equation is:

[image]

Lx and Ly are the gradients of the image (Lxx is the x-component gradient of Lx, etc [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.175.850&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is a link to the paper). The expected output should look something like this:

[image]

But all I'm getting with my code is a white image with a few black dots. Here is the code:

```
Mat img, curvedness;
Mat LX, LY, LXX, LXY, LYX, LYY;

sobelFilter(img, LX, LY);                   
sobelFilter(LX, LXX, LXY);              
sobelFilter(LY, LYX, LYY);

// calculate curvedness
multiply(LXX,LXX,LXX);  // LXX^2
multiply(LXY,LXY,LXY);  // LXY^2
multiply(2,LXY,LXY);    // 2*LXY^2
multiply(LYY,LYY,LYY);  // LYY^2

add(LXX,LXY,img);
add(LYY,img,img);
pow(img,0.5,curvedness);
imshow( window_name, curvedness);
```

The sobelFilter() code is as follows:

```
void sobelFilter(Mat img, Mat &grad_x, Mat &grad_y) 
{
    // Sobel parameters
    int scale = 1;
    int delta = 0;
    int ddepth = CV_64F;
    Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y;

    Sobel( img, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
    convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x );
    Sobel( img, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, 3, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
    convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y );
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you look at your images from the intermediate steps and see if they have reasonable values? Make sure that the images are represented as doubles and not ints.

Comment: They seem to be ints, how do I convert cv::Mat elements? Google search didn't turn up anything

Comment: Maybe the values aren't scaled between 0 and 1? cv::imshow for floating point values means: <=0:black; >=1:white; in between:gray. Maybe try `imshow( window_name, curvedness/bigFloatValue);`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your input image is of type float and not int. See this answer for how to convert an int Mat to a float one.
[Convert uchar Mat to float Mat in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302171/convert-uchar-mat-to-float-mat-in-opencv)