# OpenCV max possible value of a Mat type

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I want to find if there is a utility function or variable that outputs the maximum value a specific Mat type can take. For example, the maximum possible value of a CV_U8 is 255.

## Example case

Matlab has a couple of built in functions which can take an image of arbitrary image type and convert it (with scaling if necessary) to another image type.

For example, Matlab has the function `im2double`. Running `help im2double` shows:

```
Class Support
-------------
Intensity and truecolor images can be uint8, uint16, double, logical,
single, or int16. Indexed images can be uint8, uint16, double or
logical. Binary input images must be logical. The output image is double.
```

So it will run on 10 different image types, and outputs a double image with the same number of color channels, scaled by dividing the max allowable value in the original data type.

Thus the OpenCV functions `convertTo()` and `normalize()` would be able to do the same thing if one was able to get the max value of the input data type and input it into those functions.

In particular `convertTo(dst, type, scale)` would work identically if one could use `scale = 1/<max_value_of_input_type>` and `normalize(src, dst, alpha, beta, NORM_MINMAX)` would work with `alpha = <src_min>/<max_value_of_input_type>` and `beta = <src_max>/<max_value_of_input_type>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert uchar Mat to float Mat in OpenCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302171/convert-uchar-mat-to-float-mat-in-opencv)

Comment: @DenizBeker I'm not asking how to convert an image when the type is known---I referenced the two methods for that in my question. I'm interested in converting an image of arbitrary Mat type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility function `saturate_cast()` can perform clipping to the min and max value of a wanted type. In order to divide by the max possible value of an arbitrary type, use the biggest number an image type can take in OpenCV and saturate it with the destination type the same as the image. This will work for unsigned images. For images with signed values, saturate on the positive and negative side, and then shift and scale.

See the OpenCV docs for `saturate_cast` here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#gab93126370b85fda2c8bfaf8c811faeaf

Edit: The obvious solution is to just write the seven if statements for the different available Mat types: CV_8U, CV_8S, CV_16U, CV_16S, CV_32S, CV_32F, CV_64F, which I suppose would not be too annoying and much more clear to a reader.

Comment: Are you still working on the source code? Would be nice to have the source code here as well.